# URL rewrite rule fails match when adding +

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

The following rewrite rule works for URL:

https://www.example.com/muziek/liedjes-start+meeting/modern

But with this URL I get `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`
https://www.example.com/muziek/liedjes-start+meeting/rhythm+and+blues

```
  <rule name="song overview occasion + genre">
    <match url="^(muziek/liedjes|music/songs)-([a-zA-Z-+]+)/([a-zA-Z-+]+)$"/>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="songs.aspx?category={R:2}&amp;genre={R:3}" appendQueryString="true"/>
  </rule>
```

So fot the second URL the rewrite does not work...why not?

Comment: Try escaping `+` and `-` in `url`.

Comment: Thanks! Using `([a-zA-Z\-\+]+)` for the last variable worked, but I don't understand how it then can be that my first URL, containing `liedjes-start+meeting` works without escaping that variable? I kept that condition on `([a-zA-Z-+]+)`

Comment: Strange enough. It was just a guess from my side. I don't use ASP (but do have some experience with RewriteEngine and RegExp).